# Excel Formula that copys Column Title based off related data within row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, column, title

I am looking for a formula to represent what is in the highlighted section of the excel sheet. For example, for invoice 4/1/2022, i would like a formula for "payable for" that lists (1)Invoice Date and (2) A, B since these two titles have values within the respective cells.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use TEXTJOIN and concatenate the date:

```
=TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy, ")&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($B$1:$D$1,B2:D2<>"",""))
```

[image]